# Android XML - ImageView scrolling

Tags: android, xml

A sprite on my android game is set to fall by 5 pixels every 100 milliseconds, this works fine the only problem is that the ImageView itself is only 53dp high, if I make it any bigger the image inside scales with it. Since the ImageView is only 53dp high the image disappears after 1100 milliseconds as it scrolls outside the boundaries of the imageview.

I need the layout height of the ImageView to fill_parent but I need the image to stay the same size instead of scaling with it, here's my current code:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blueman"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:paddingRight="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:src="@drawable/fall" />
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't give the full code of the layout, I'll make some assumptions...
you're talking about setting your sprite's height to the screen's height without scaling?

There should be a difference between your screen size (that is the root layout item) and the sprites in it. I guess you declared your layout as...:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="?gameBackground"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btTap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tap"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btCellR1C1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="490dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cell_red" />
```

The only thing I had to cope with, was the scaling of my sprites depending on the device's resolution with such a method:

```
public static void scaleView(View view, int top, int left, int width,
        int height) {
    top = Math.round(top * scaleY);
    left = Math.round(left * scaleX);
    width = Math.round(width * scaleX);
    height = Math.round(height * scaleY);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.height = height;
    params.width = width;
    params.topMargin = top;
    params.leftMargin = left;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);

    view.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
}
```

Please give us more details to help you

Best regards
Serge